Removing \n from HTML asset retrieved via an API
I'm trying to use cloud page to use API to retrieve the HTML email to display on cloud page. I can get the API to work, but it adds '\n' and \ to my html code that was retrieved, which breaks the rendering. I've tried a various methods to try and remove it (mainly with chatgpt) but to no avail.
My code right now has
       // Log status and content for debugging
        Write('HTTP Status: ' + results.status + '<br>');
        Write('Response Content: ' + results.content + '<br>');

        if (results.status == 200) {
            // Log the raw HTML content for inspection
            Write('Raw HTML Content: <pre>' + results.content + '</pre>');

            // Replace escaped newline characters along with preceding and trailing spaces
            var cleanedHtml = results.content.replace(/\\n/g, '');

            // Log cleaned HTML content for inspection
            Write('Cleaned HTML Content: <pre>' + cleanedHtml + '</pre>');
        } else {
            Write('Failed to retrieve the content. Status: ' + results.status + '<br>');
        }
    } else {
        Write('Failed to get access token. Status: ' + accessTokenRequest.StatusCode + '<br>');
    }
} catch (error) {
    Write('Error: ' + Stringify(error) + '<br>');
}

However, even with the replace, it doesn't remove the \n or \  that are being added in to the code. Any ideas how to fix this so the email can render correctly?

Breaks the rendering how? Outside of certain markup scenarios with <pre>, \n (and whatever is \) is not a meaningful character in HTML

results.content.replace(/\\n/g, '') is not valid for String.replace; first arg must be a string - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replace

@identigral it breaks the rendering because it adds \n into the html that was retrieved. Ie. table \n style="\text-align:\nleft....
Need to remove those in the html that was retrieved so it can render correctly on cloudpage. It's being inserted after the api retrieves the asset.
